# how to retrieve player names who never scored a century?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Data is like this. So, I want to see the list of Players who never scored a Century in their entire career. 
Sample Data

[image]

Comment: What even *is* a century?

Comment: Don't forget `HAVING`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, probably 100 (points).

Comment: With that sample data, what is the expected result?

Comment: @jarlh I assume so, I just wanted to point out that not enough information is given to answer this question/assignment

Comment: Expected Result:  Kumble and Prasad

Comment: If you add (7, Prasad 90), will the expected result change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Group by`.. `Having` clause with `MAX()` to find out players name who never scored century

```
SELECT NAME FROM table
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING MAX(SCORE) < 100;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i am not getting desired output.output should be Kumble and Prasad because they never scored centuries.

Comment: @PavanKumar.. this above `sql` query is right but you may check with ur side why you are not getting the result that you want because in our side the query working fine or you could show us what query attempt.

Comment: Hi, This the query i use "select name from cric group by name having max(score) < 100" and output is Kumble, Prasad and Sachin

Comment: @PavanKumar may be you have some bad data !!

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte 
AS(
    SELECT 'Sachin' [NAME], 123 [Score]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Sachin' [NAME], 44 [Score]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Kumble' [NAME], 22 [Score]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Kumble' [NAME], 77 [Score]
)
SELECT
    X.NAME
    ,MAX(X.Score)
FROM cte X
GROUP BY
    X.NAME
HAVING
    MAX(X.Score) < 100
```

Answer (score 0):

use `GROUP BY ... HAVING`

```
SELECT name
FROM table1
GROUP BY name
HAVING MAX(score) < 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, here the table name is tblScore

```
select name,max(score) max_score from tblScore group by name
having max(score)<100
```

The result is

```
|name   | max_score|
....................
|kumble | 77
|prasad | 12
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i am not getting desired output.output should be Kumble and Prasad because they never scored centuries.

Comment: Thanks for you comment . Output should be Kumble and Prasad because they never scored centuries. I just show the scores for matching your desire result.

Comment: Hi, This the query i use "select name from cric group by name having max(score) < 100" and output is Kumble, Prasad and Sachin

Comment: how Sachin  will come.  I run the same query (select name from tblScore group by name
having max(score)<100) the result is kumble and
prasad

Answer (score 0):

Try `Group By` and `Having` Combination

```
SELECT
    name
FROM [Table Name]
GROUP BY
    name
HAVING
    MAX(score) < 100
```